# how to unzip a file using unzip command?

Tags: bash, zip, unzip

I have an script which creates a folder named "data". Then it downloads a file using `wget` and these files (.zip format) are moved from the current directory to the folder "data". After that what I want is to unzip these files. I'm using `unzip filename.zip` and it works when I use it on the cmd, however I don't know why it's not working in the script.

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir data

wget http://187.191.75.115/gobmx/salud/datos_abiertos/datos_abiertos_covid19.zip && mv datos_abiertos_covid19.zip data && unzip datos_abiertos_covid19.zip
wget http://187.191.75.115/gobmx/salud/datos_abiertos/diccionario_datos_covid19.zip && mv diccionario_datos_covid19.zip data && unzip diccionario_datos_covid19.zip
```

*datos_abiertos_covid19.zip* and *diccionario_datos_covid19.zip* are the files I want to unzip once they are in my folder "data". I would really appreciate if someone can help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: yep, and if there is no directory named data, `mv` will rename your zip files to data, a work around is to add a trailing slash to the directory, in this case `data/` so mv will error out a message that there is no directory named `data/`, as oppose to just renaming your files to data.

Comment: @Jetchisel : There likely **is** a directory of this name (see the `mkdir` command in front).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It fails because `unzip foo.zip` assumes `foo.zip` is in the current directory, but you just moved it to a subdirectory `data`. Interactively, you probably `cd data` first and that's why it works.

To make it work in your script, just have your script `cd data` as well:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir data
cd data || exit 1
wget http://187.191.75.115/gobmx/salud/datos_abiertos/datos_abiertos_covid19.zip && unzip datos_abiertos_covid19.zip
```

That way, the file is downloaded directly to the `data` directory so no `mv` is necessary, and the unzip command works as expected.

Comment: Would `mkdir -p data` be better?

Comment: @jared_mamrot : Much better, because you don't get an error message, if the directory exists already.  An alternative would be to do a `[[ -d data ]] || mkdir data`.

Answer (score 0):

My approach:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e    # Exit if any command fails

mkdir data
pushd ./data >/dev/null

for i in 'datos_abiertos_covid19.zip' 'diccionario_datos_covid19.zip'; do
        # Don't unzip (or exit) if 'wget' fails, don't exit if 'unzip' fails
        wget "http://187.191.75.115/gobmx/salud/datos_abiertos/$i" -O "./$i" || continue
        unzip "./$i" || true
done

popd >/dev/null
```

- The file names don't need to be quoted in this case, but I did so anyway, to emphasise you can/should do so if necessary
- You could of course use variables for the file list, URL, download dir, etc. if you wanted to build a more general script for downloading zip files
- I know it's marked bash, but worth mentioning: `pushd` and `popd` are not defined in POSIX, you can change those to `cd ./data` and `cd ..` for more portability. Obviously `wget` is not POSIX either, but very common (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9490872/is-wget-or-similar-programs-always-available-on-posix-systems) thread for interesting info on that topic)